# Anaconda's Spyder with Pygame has a fatal error during the second play of the program in console

Tags: python, pygame, anaconda, spyder

The second time I play the program in the console, it has a 'fatal error'.

I have been solving this by moving to a new console, but I'm still worried that this could cause problems later.

Code:

```
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *
    board = pygame.display.set_mode((400,600))

    #colors
    black = pygame.Color(0, 0, 0)      
    white = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)  
    grey = pygame.Color(128, 128, 128)   
    red = pygame.Color(255, 0, 0)     
    blue  = pygame.Color(0, 0, 255)  
    green=pygame.Color(0,255,0)

    board.fill(white)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Sigil")

    class Card (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self,image,x,y):
            super().__init__() 
            #above is magic class code that shouldn't be messed with (mostly)
            #inuit only happens once
    
            self.x=x
            self.y=y 
            self.image=image
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            board.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))
    
        def update(self):
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
     
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                self.rect.move_ip(0, -5)
               
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                self.rect.move_ip(0,5)
               
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
               
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                self.rect.move_ip(5, 0)
        def draw(self, surface):
            surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)     

    test=pygame.image.load("Twitter-icon.png") #Make sure to add .png
    test=pygame.transform.scale(test,(test.get_width()/2,test.get_height()/2))

    P1 = Card(test,10,10)

    print_message=pygame.USEREVENT + 0
    pygame.time.set_timer(print_message, 3000) #can be used to make longer loops for your loop

    #Frames Per Second
    clock=pygame.time.Clock()
    #Game Loop

    while True:
     
          #All functions dependent on user input need to be part of this loop- event.get clears the event que
          for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit() 
            if event.type == print_message:
                print("Hello World")
            P1.update()
            board.fill(white)
            P1.draw(board)
            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(20)
```

Here's the error

```
    Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault

    Thread 0x00008390 (most recent call first):
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\parentpoller.py", line 97 in run
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

    Thread 0x0000586c (most recent call first):
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\socket.py", line 475 in 
    recv_multipart
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\session.py", line 803 in recv
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 
    114 in poll_one
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 
    104 in poll_thread
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870 in run
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

    Thread 0x00005f14 (most recent call first):
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 296 in wait
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 552 in wait
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\history.py", line 829 in run
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\history.py", line 58 in 
    needs_sqlite
    File "", line 2 in run
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

    Thread 0x00006c64 (most recent call first):
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\heartbeat.py", line 100 in run
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

    Thread 0x00006558 (most recent call first):
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\selectors.py", line 314 in _select
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\selectors.py", line 323 in select
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1746 in _run_once
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 538 in run_forever
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 153 in 
    start
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\iostream.py", line 78 in _ 
    thread_main
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870 in run
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

    Current thread 0x000060c8 (most recent call first):
    File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\Python Scripts\Cardgame(sigil)prototype.py", line 4 in 
    File 
    "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", 
    line 377 in exec_code
    File 
    "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", 
    line 476 in runfile
    File "", line 1 in 
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331 
    in run_code
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3254 
    in run_ast_nodes
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3063 
    in run_cell_async
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 68 in 
    _pseudo_sync_runner
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2886 
    in _run_cell
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2858 
    in run_cell
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 536 in run_cell
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 300 in 
    do_execute
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209 in wrapper
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 541 in 
    execute_request
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209 in wrapper
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 268 in 
    dispatch_shell
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209 in wrapper
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 361 in 
    process_one
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\tornado\gen.py", line 748 in run
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\tornado\gen.py", line 787 in inner
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 743 in 
    _run_callback
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 690 in 
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 88 in _run
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1782 in _run_once
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 538 in run_forever
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 153 in 
    start
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 583 in start
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 318 
    in main
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 11 
    in 
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85 in _run_code
    File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193 in _run_module_as_main
```

Due to my lack of experience, my state of understanding is "WTF" due to me realizing (while inputting) that this error is longer than my entire program.

Answer (score 0):

IDE's like spyder tend to run your code differently than when you run it from a `cmd` window.

So if your program crashes or behaves weird in an IDE, the *first thing to try* is to save it as a file and run it from a `cmd` window as `python filename.py` and see if that works as intended.
If it does, mark it down as an IDE bug/feature.

I would say that this is particularly relevant for programs that use graphics toolkits like `pygame` or `tkinter`. Or programs that use `multiprocessing`, `threading` or `subprocess`.